# A/B testing - Non deterministic changes - statistical significance

Tags: hypothesis-testing, confidence-interval

We are running an A/B test for a trivia game to improve retention (The percentage of players that come back for a second day of playing).

I am still a beginner in with this.

Trying to compare the proportions of two samples, (in a deterministic test like changing the text in a button), things would look like:

$$\mu_{a-b} = \mu_a - \mu_b$$
$$var_a = p_a * (1-p_a) / n$$
$$var_b = p_b * (1-p_b) / m$$
$$sd_{a-b} = \sqrt{var_a + var_b}$$
$$1.96 * sd_{a-b} \pm \mu_{a-b} = interval$$

Howerver, this test is non deterministic.

We want to test if the **Difficulty** of the questions a user gets will affect retention.

**Difficulty** is defined as the proportion of incorrect answers. Therefore taking values from the interval [0,1].

Players in either the control or the easy group will get questions randomly but from different *bags of questions*.

We then have 2 *bags of questions*.

1. The control bag. With all the questions.
2. The easy bag. A subset of the control bag, removing the top 33% most difficult questions.

Control bag difficulty:
Mean: .56
SD: .19

Easy bag difficulty:
Mean: .46
SD: .16

[image: Question bags difficulty distribution]

Because the easy questions are a subset of the control questions, there is a chance that users will get the same questions. Or questions of the same difficulty.

This should clearly affect the size of the significance of the results, but I don't know how to account for it. How could this be archived?

Answer (score 0):

reframe the problem.

try to find out for every question, what happens to that question 'retention' if the question is asked as part of a hard group, or as part of an easy group.

Run experiment N times. Then build a table such as:

- col A      |      col B (N)     |             col C (N)
- Question # | retention when hard bag | retention when part of easy
- 1 .......... .31 ..........         .30
- 2 ..........  .04..........         .33
- 3 
  and so on

then  plot x = Question ordered by difficulty  y = B,C, plot a regression with R (with confidence intervals.) See if they overlap or not.

Furthermore, you can run a significance test for every row
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_test